# DAG to trigger any new file upload in GCS path

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, airflow-2.x

I am trying to Trigger a DAG for any new file upload or a file update in a particular GCS path,

Tried `GCSObjectUpdateSensor` but for it to work, I should pass the object name - `Stage/staging/test.txt`  like this.

I am looking for a sensor to sense any update or new upload to the path - `Stage/staging/`

My DAG code looks like this (Sample code given):

```
with DAG(
    dag_id="test_sensor",
    default_args=DEFAULT_ARGS,
    dagrun_timeout=timedelta(hours=96),
    start_date=datetime(2023, 8, 16),
    schedule_interval=timedelta(minutes=5),
    catchup=False,
) as dag:

    gcs_file_sensor = GCSObjectUpdateSensor(
         task_id='gcs_file_sensor',
         bucket="cs-us-ds",
         object='Stage/staging/', 
         timeout=30,
         dag=dag,
         soft_fail='true')

    def sleep_task(task_id):
        task = BashOperator(
            task_id=task_id,
            bash_command="sleep 20",
        )
        return task

    wait_phase1 = sleep_task("wait_phase1")

gcs_file_sensor >> wait_phase1
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, you use a sensor on an object. It exists another sensor, on a prefix: [`GCSObjectsWithPrefixExistenceSensor`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/_api/airflow/providers/google/cloud/sensors/gcs/index.html#airflow.providers.google.cloud.sensors.gcs.GCSObjectsWithPrefixExistenceSensor).

Remember, there is no folder in Cloud Storage, so the prefix in the object fully qualified name prefix!

Comment: `GCSObjectsWithPrefixExistenceSensor` always gets triggered if I give the `prefix='Stage/staging/'`, is there a way to trigger it only when a file is available in the path `'Stage/staging/'`

Comment: You mean, when a new file arrive. don't matter the other file, right?

Comment: Yes, I would like to get the job triggered on a new file arrival to the path -`'Stage/staging/'`

Comment: Ok, in that case, I use eventarc + Cloud Run which invokes the correct DAG on Composer. Composer is not an event listener, you must put a piece in the middle.